# How faster is using an internal IP address instead of an external one?

Tags: linux, email, smtp

I have a mailing list application that sends emails through several dedicated SMTP servers (running Linux Debian 5 and Postfix) in the same network of a hosting company.

However, the application is using the servers' external IP addresses in order to connect to them over SMTP, and I was wondering what kind of improvement would be obtained if the application used the internal IP addresses of the servers instead?

Thank you in advance for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

- Ask the **network admins**
- Check the **routes**. Do a traceroute. More hops can mean slower if the hops are used for connecting lots of subnets.
- Test the **latency**. Do some pings. If the route is used much more than the others, it can be slower.
- Test the **throughput speed**. Do some speedtests.

Be careful testing speed though: **ask first** if you're allowed to stress the network during daytime (work) hours...

Usually though, for sending an e-mail, using IP-address A or B won't be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the network compontents "between" the application and the (SMTP-)server (like firewalls, routers, switches...) it can differ a lot, but in most cases using the internal address should be faster.

This question is more a network question and should be asked to the people responsible for this specific network.